# Position 0 is not getting selected in Spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a spinner that has three items

Daily

Weekly

Monthly

I did the following in my java file:

```
navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.dailyview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.weekview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.monthview)));

        adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);
        mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

OnItemSelected method (Implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {

        Log.e("Position", "= " + position);

        if (mNaviFirstHit)
        {
            mNaviFirstHit = false;
        }
        else
        {

            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    Log.e("Week", "= " + position);
                    break;

                case 1:

                    backspace = 1;

                    Log.e("Week", "= " + position);

                    break;

                case 2:

                    backspace = 1;

                    Log.e("Week", "= " + position);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class TitleNavigationAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private TextView txtTitle;
    private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem;
    private Context context;
    private TextView txtHeading;
    private SharedPreferences pref;

    public TitleNavigationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem) 
    {
        this.spinnerNavItem = spinnerNavItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return spinnerNavItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) 
    {
        return spinnerNavItem.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    { 
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_title, null);
        }

        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());

        txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orangeText));
        txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = pref.getString("selectedItem", context.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_gridview));

        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_gridview)))
        {
            txtTitle.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_gridview_text));
        }
        else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_weekview)))
        {
            txtTitle.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_weekly_text));
        }
        else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_monthview)))
        {
            txtTitle.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.transaction_main_monthly_text));
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_title, null);
        }

        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtTitle.setPadding(20, 20, 0, 20);

        txtHeading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtheading);
        txtHeading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The above code works fine when I select position 1 or 2 (I get the logs properly) then from position 1 or 2 if I select position 0 the Log is not printed at all. Position doesn't get called. Even just the position log is not getting printed.

This is really strange I am not sure why this happening? can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: put a break point at very first line inside `onItemSelected` and debug it and check.

Comment: @Rustam: I figured out the OnItemSelected is never called because the first line didn't log the position in OnItemSelected.

Comment: you mean listener is not getting fired at all right?

Comment: @Rustam: Yep. That is right..

Comment: are the all values showing ?

Comment: if so then just remove `OnItemSelectedListener` from your activity and re implement it , clean, build and run.

Comment: @Rustam : I am not sure on what you mean by are all the values showing?

Comment: @Rustam: I tried that couple of times it didn't work. I am using this on Fragment. Do you think this would be an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83031/discussion-between-rustam-and-thedevman).

Comment: @Rustam: Any other clue in solving this issue?

Comment: Provide your adapter code, too.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer : I have added the adapter code too.

Comment: I have tried your code. And its giving me position = 0,  position = 1, position = 2 correctly. The other thing i found is, when the activity is started, at that time also, I am getting position = 0.

Comment: can you share your full Activity and Adapter class  so be can help u out

Comment: what is `mNaviFirstHit` flag for? Please also share its usage, may it can help.

Comment: @Prashant Patel When I load the fragment with the spinner the first position is automatically called hence i using a flag to say if it first don't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a Spinner in a Fragment, you must to declare it in Fragment onCreatedView(). Not in onCreate() of your FragmentActivity.

OnItemSelectedListener Must be implemented inside your FragmentMain not inside your Activity if you want to use the listener on the spinner inside the Fragment.

**These changes to your code have been tested.**

**your context comes back null (in my test code anyway):**

```
Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();// returns null !
```

**so change to:**

TitleNavigationAdapter adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(this,navSpinner);// added this

**does your Activity implent OnItemSelectedListener ?:**

```
        public class InformationList  extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    .....
```

**I would also change this in TitleNavigationAdapter:**

```
    @Override
public SpinnerNavItem getItem(int index) //SpinnerNavItem from Object
    {
        return spinnerNavItem.get(index);
    }
```

**Results:**

```
07-18 19:46:53.468: E/Position(27325): = 0
07-18 19:46:53.468: E/day(27325): = 0
07-18 19:47:04.487: E/Position(27325): = 1
07-18 19:47:04.488: E/Week(27325): = 1
07-18 19:47:06.426: E/Position(27325): = 2
07-18 19:47:06.426: E/month(27325): = 2
```

Functioning correctly.

[image: spinner]

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove `getApplicationContext()`

```
adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getActivity(), navSpinner);
```

also i think it gets called but its because of your `Log` parameters, [not filtering why](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)?, try this for all `Log` lines

```
 Log.e("Position", "= " + String.valueOf(position));
```

after you can try after setting your `onitemSelectedListener` re-set the initial selection to 0, to see if there is a significant difference

hope it helps

Comment: It is not being called when I click on Item 0. I am not sure what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**This code also works:**

```
    //inflate  
    View rootView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item_title);

        navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.dailyview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.weekview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.monthview)));

        if(navSpinner != null  && navSpinner.size() > 0)
        {
//          Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();//jrg returns null !
            TitleNavigationAdapter adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, navSpinner);//jrg

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);//
            Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);       
            mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }//OnCreate
```

**in TitleNavigationAdapter**

```
    public class TitleNavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerNavItem> 
    {

        public TitleNavigationAdapter(Context context,int resource ,ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> navSpinner) 
        {
             super(context, resource , navSpinner);//jrg
            this.spinnerNavItem = navSpinner;
            this.context = context;
        }

    .....

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    }
```

**SpinnerNavItem:**

public class SpinnerNavItem
{

```
private String title;
private int icon;

public SpinnerNavItem(String title, int icon)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public SpinnerNavItem(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
```

//        this.icon = icon;
    }

```
public String getTitle()
{
    return this.title;
}

public int getIcon()
{
    return this.icon;
}
```

}

** list_item_title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Choose Time"
        android:id="@+id/txtheading"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.dailyview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.weekview)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.monthview)));
```

---

adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);

### above line of code is not correct way to call a adapter

as if you are calling the adapter in any Activity you should call like this

```
adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(this, navSpinner);
            mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

or

```
adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(YourActivityNAme.this, navSpinner);
```

else any where from you r calling this adpater like in Fragment or listView,Gridview etc from any where you call inflate the layout out side of the Activity you need to pass the Context or that Activity class reference like

```
Context cntxt;//declare in class
  cntxt=getActivity()//in  oncreate() in case or fragment
cntxt=context;//by passing the Activity reference in the constructor  of YourClassName class
```

`context` is the value which is been passed in constructor  like `YourClassName(Context context ,...other parameters){....}`

```
 adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(cntxt, navSpinner);
                mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

also here you are using this in the `setOnItemSelectedListener` so u need to provide the implementation of this listener in same class whom reference you pass here so 
 `public class YourClassName extends YourExtendsClassName implements OnItemSelectedListener {......}` and all above code goes inside of this class or you rest code related to this class
or you can do this

```
 mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.e("Position", "= " + position);

            if (mNaviFirstHit)
            {
            mNaviFirstHit = false;
            }
            else
            {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        Log.e("Week", "= " + position);
                        break;

                    case 1:

                        backspace = 1;

                        Log.e("Week", "= " + position);

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        backspace = 1;

                        Log.e("Week", "= " + position);

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

and also you need to modify for safer side 
you should also change this in TitleNavigationAdapter:

```
 @Override
public SpinnerNavItem getItem(int index) //SpinnerNavItem from Object
    {
        return spinnerNavItem.get(index);
    }
```

and your code will also run for the position 0 element
also please check the logic which you have written in the `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){...}`
and
 if you want really help please provide full information
instead of broken piece of code

as per now you can see the log for position 0 also

Answer (score 0):

spbBloodGrp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            String bloodgroup = "";

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String bloodgroup = spbBloodGrp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (position != 0) {
                bloodgroup = spbBloodGrp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), bloodgroup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etxtbloodGrp.setText(bloodgroup);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

It will help u, good luck

Answer (score 0):

you just need set selection default. everything solved

```
spinner.setSelection(0)
```